# Asymptotic behaviour of Bayes factor for normal model

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

I'm given two models:

> $M_1: X \sim N(x|\theta_0,1)$
>
> $M_2: X \sim N(x|\theta,1) \land \pi(\theta|M_2) =
>  N(\theta|\theta_0,1)$
>
> Assume that, $\pi(M_1) = \pi(M_2) = 1/2$.

I need to compute the Bayes factor and study its asymptotic behaviour.

$B_{21}(x) = \frac{m(x|M_1)}{m(x|M_2)}$

Clearly, $m(x|M_1) = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^n} e^{-n(\overline{x}-\theta_0)^2/2} e^{-nS^2/2}$

$$m(x|M_2) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x|\theta,M_2) \pi(\theta|M_2) d \theta = \int_\mathbb{R} N(x|\theta,1) N(\theta|\theta_0,1) d\theta = \frac{e^{-nS^2/2}}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^{n+1}}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-n(\overline{x} - \theta)^2/2}e^{-(\theta-\theta_0)^2/2}d\theta$$

But how do can I integrate this term?

A simpler approach may be related with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590924/on-the-identity-int-nz-mu-sigma-02n-mu-mu-0-sigma-12-d-mu-nz-sig).

Comment: have you tried combining the two exponents and then completing the square to get something that looks like a scaled normal distribution?

Comment: @BrianBorchers combining the two exponents gives me an ugly integral. i haven't tried completing squares. what you mean by scaled normal distribution?

Comment: You should end up with something like an integral of $e^{(\theta-p)^{2}/2}$ (where $p$ depends on $\theta_{0}$, $n$, and $\bar{x}$) after completing the square.  You already know how to integrate the normal distribution, so you can evaluate that integral as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming the formula in link**

The Bayes factor assuming the formula in the link would be $B_{21}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}exp\Big(\frac{n^2(\overline{x}-\theta_0)^2}{2(n+1)}\Big)$ and it remains to study how does this distribution behave asymptotically for the different assumed models.

Under the assmuption that $M_1$ holds one has that $\sqrt{n} (\overline{x} - \theta_0) \to N(0,1/I(\theta_0))$ by assymptotic normality of the m.l.e. Therefore, the square converges to a $\chi_1^2$ and the bayes factor goes to zero. For the other assumption one uses the central limit theorem in the Lindeberg's-Levy formulation and finds that the bayes factor goes to $\infty$.

This gives the consistency of the test.